# DataSource's Connection didn't reconnect, when set BreakAfterAcquireFailure to true

Tags: java, mysql, connection-pooling, c3p0

I have set BreakAfterAcquireFailure to true, MaxIdleTime and MaxConnectionAge's value are 10 (very small).Like below:

```
ComboPooledDataSource ds = new ComboPooledDataSource(db);
ds.setAcquireRetryAttempts(3);
ds.setBreakAfterAcquireFailure(true);
ds.setMaxIdleTime(10);
ds.setMaxConnectionAge(10);
ds.setMaxPoolSize(2);
ds.setMinPoolSize(1);
ds.setTestConnectionOnCheckin(false);
ds.setIdleConnectionTestPeriod(10);
ds.setPreferredTestQuery("select 1");
```

Why ComboPooledDataSource.getConnection() always throw exception, after restarting the mysql for a long time.

Who can help me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`breakAfterAcquireFailure` [means](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#breakAfterAcquireFailure) precisely that c3p0 will *not* try to recover from a dbms outage. if `breakAfterAcquireFailure` is set, the DataSource eill simply mark itself broken if it finds it cannot acquire new Connections, and never try again. if you want your DataSource to recover from an outtage, leave that parameter at its default value of `false`.

You don't want such small values for `maxIdleTime` and `maxConnectionAge`. That's terrible. If you are relying upon idle Connection tests, it's a good idea to also set `testConnectionOnCheckin` to `true`. 10 seconds is probably more aggressive than you need for `idleConnectionTestPeriod`. Given your pool size params, I presume you are just testing / playing with this, though. (`maxPoolSize` of 2 is way too small for most uses.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  The purpose of setting breakAfterAcquireFailure to true is that I want `c3p0` immediately return for protect application itself, when `mysql` is down, insteading of waiting until reach timeout.  By the way, I set `maxIdelTime`, `maxConnectionAge`, `maxPoolSize`, `minPoolSize` are just for test. Thanks for your remind.

Comment: c3p0 will detect Connections are dead when it tests those Connections. a tight idleConnectionTestPeriod will cause the stale Connections to be expunged quickly. (10 secs is probably too tight.) breakAfterAcquireFailure=true will cause your DataSource to never reconnect. if false, c3p0 will try to reconnect when new clients arrive.